# Remove caption tag

Tags: php

Could anyone help with a regular express that could remove:
`[caption id="attachment_116" align="alignnone" width="300"]`

Where the `*` could be anything:
`[caption * ]`

Cheers - Working in PHP

Comment: you need to frame your question correctly, provide more details, and also mention what you had tried. This helps more than cheering for working in PHP :)

Comment: Please add a `RegEx` tag in your question.

Comment: Do you want to make `[caption id="attachment_116" align="alignnone" width="300"]` as `[caption]` ?

Comment: I'm just after removing it completely and have little or no experience with Reg Expressions so a bit lost!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then try this pattern:

```
(\[caption\s+?[^]]+\])
```

a Replace with this pattern will remove all `[caption * ]`